# What is wrong with my code why i cant assign Float Real in this code in SQL

Tags: sql

```
declare
    @num float
set @num=(1/17)
select @num as result
```

**my result is 0**

Comment: That's not (standard) SQL to begin with. Are you using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Integer division maybe, `1.0/17`? _(Never done what you did.)_

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `1.0 / 17` or `1 / 17.0` because integer division is always return `integer`.

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT
SET @num = 1.0/17
SELECT @num AS result
```

**0.058823**

```
DECLARE @num DECIMAL(18,2)
SET @num = 1/17.0
SELECT @num AS result
```

**0.06**

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    @num float
set @num=(CAST(1 AS FLOAT)/17)
select @num as result
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7j4K.png)

Comment: I Prefer Use CAST(1 AS FLOAT) Replace of 1.0 Because 1 May be Refer to Integer Variable